How Do I Run A Command In Bash Using Specific Version of Python
I have a website which runs on a VPS and I use CyberPanel for some admin purposes. A week or two ago I received an email saying I should update the version of CyberPanel as it was vulnerable. When I try to log onto it I get a 500 internal error saying "The server encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling the request".
I'm trying to upgrade CyberPanel, have the commands to do so but getting a python version error.
I've spent a couple of days on CyberPanel's message boards. My first approach was to upgrade the panel, there's a command which is supposed to do the job:
sh <(curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/usmannasir/cyberpanel/stable/preUpgrade.sh || wget -O - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/usmannasir/cyberpanel/stable/preUpgrade.sh)
That did some things but then failed with:
"protobuf requires Python '>=3.7' but the running Python is 3.6.8".
Sure enough, "python3 --version" indicated I was on 3.6.8.
I then spent a while trying different things to upgrade python, eventually installing pyenv and version 3.11.3. Now "python3 --version" tells me I'm on Python 3.11.3.
However, when I run the upgrade command again I get the same error as before saying I'm on 3.6.8.
I've also tried a few things as suggested on their boards to combat their hack (kinsing removal script, various pings, checking htop etc), but indications are that the hack isn't my problem.
I've looked at the .sh file in the script but I don't speak much UNIX, have never done anything with Python (don't even see where it comes in) and don't know what protobuf is. So what I would like to know is, what do I need to do to run that command so it uses the right version of Python? I think pyenv should make that possible somehow, but how?
Thanks in advance.

What version of Linux are you running?  It might simply be time to upgrade your LInux version, which will install a new Python system-wide.  You installed a new Python for your own personal use in a virtual environment, but that doesn't change the system version, and that's what CyberPanel will use.

hi Tim, thanks for the reply.
Using "uname -r" it tells me 3.10.0
For "cat /etc/os-release"
NAME="CentOS Linux"
VERSION="7 (Core)"
ID="centos"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="7"
PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Linux 7 (Core)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:centos:centos:7"
HOME_URL="https://www.centos.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.centos.org/"
CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT="CentOS-7"
CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT_VERSION="7"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="centos"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7"

Honestly.  Fedora 7 was released in 2003 and is old enough ti drink in America.  It reached end-of-life in 2008.  It is long past time for you to upgrade.  It's dangerous to have a public-facing server using a 16-year-old operating system.

Preliminary statement
As pointed out by @TimRoberts in this comment, your CentOS 7 distro is obsolete, CentOS 7 reached its end-of-life in June 2024. The best thing to do is to upgrade your OS, as this can pose security threats especially for a public-facing server.
Solving the Python issue you described
Internally, you're calling the preUpgrade.sh script from here which fetches the version number from this text file and grabs the corresponding cyberpanel_upgrade.sh script from there (here, v2.3.8).
This last script seems to explicitly use python36 (see line 395), so I think a simple workaround would be to run the preUpgrade.sh script you already have the link to, but right before the last line you can add a line with:
sed -i "s/python36/python37/g" "/usr/local/cyberpanel_upgrade.sh"

This line will replace all occurrences of python36 with python37 in the cyberpanel_upgrade.sh file you downloaded.

Great thanks, @globglogabgalab. At work just now but will try that later tonight or maybe tomorrow. Cheers

Keep us updated!

Also, that may warrant a ticket/issue to cyber-panel, this is clearly an issue on their side that they can easily fix

and TimRoberts thanks for that. I tried your suggestion tonight but just ended up with the same error. I checked the upgrade file afterwards it did do the substitution but that made no difference. I can probably live without CyberPanel for now, the only thing I use it for these days is SSL certificates and I'm sure I can find another way of issuing them. I'll look into upgrading the OS. I'm a bit disappointed in that, I signed up for this less than two years ago, I'd have thought it would have come with something a bit more up to date. Thanks again, both of you.
